# AS3 Number, Int to Bytes/Char

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Is there a code base that would allow the conversion of most common number types to be converted to byte/char. Im looking for a simple conversion using any codebase, or as3 default code base. Not the int to byte formulae.

The idea is to convert large numbers into char bytes, so as to save space for string transmission of data over the net. As oppose to converting every digit to a string character.

The shorter the as3 code is to implement, the better.

Comment: the AMF format does this and some other nifty compression tricks, it may be worth looking into if you want to move large amounts of data in a hurry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ByteArray` class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html has methods for reading/writing ints, floats, doubles etc. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Was hopeing there was something better :)  But this will work

Comment: IMHO you should use ByteArray or Vector for what you appear to want. Like @grapefrukt says, "Adobe performs some tricks" when they encode the data for transmission. With BA you can also compress before sending.